# How to get output in desired encoding scheme using powershell out-fil

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a requirement, in which I need to do read line by line, and then do string/character replacement in a datafile having data in windows latin 1.

I've written this powershell (my first one) initially using `out-file -encoding` option. However the output file thus created was doing some character translation. Then I searched and came across `WriteAllLines`, but I'm unable to use it in my code.

```
$encoding =[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1')
$pdsname="ABCD.XYZ.PQRST"
$datafile="ABCD.SCHEMA.TABLE.DAT"
Get-Content ABCD.SCHEMA.TABLE.DAT | ForEach-Object {
$matches = [regex]::Match($_,'ABCD')
$string_to_be_replaced=$_.substring($matches.Index,$pdsname.Length+10)
$string_to_be_replaced="`"$string_to_be_replaced`""
$member = [regex]::match($_,"`"$pdsname\(([^\)]+)\)`"").Groups[1].Value
$_ -replace $([regex]::Escape($string_to_be_replaced)),$member 
} | [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("C:\Users\USer01", "ABCD.SCHEMA.TABLE.NEW.DAT", $encoding)
```

With the help of an answer from @Gzeh Niert, I updated my above script. However, when I execute the script the output file being generated by the script has just the last record, as it was unable to append, and it did an overwrite, I tried using System.IO.File]::AppendAllText, but this strangely creates a larger file, and has only the last record. In short its likely that empty lines are being written.

```
param(

    [String]$datafile
)
$pdsname="ABCD.XYZ.PQRST"
$encoding =[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1')
$datafile = "ABCD.SCHEMA.TABLE.DAT"
$datafile2="ABCD.SCHEMA.TABLE.NEW.DAT"
Get-Content $datafile | ForEach-Object {
    $matches = [regex]::Match($_,'ABCD')
    if($matches.Success) {
    $string_to_be_replaced=$_.substring($matches.Index,$pdsname.Length+10)
    $string_to_be_replaced="`"$string_to_be_replaced`""
    $member = [regex]::match($_,"`"$pdsname\(([^\)]+)\)`"").Groups[1].Value
    $replacedContent = $_ -replace $([regex]::Escape($string_to_be_replaced)),$member
    [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($datafile2, $replacedContent, $encoding)
    }
    else {
        [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($datafile2, $_, $encoding)
        }
    #[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($datafile2, $replacedContent, $encoding)
}
```

Please help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: The `WriteAllLines` must be out of the `ForEach-Object` loop, otherwise you are writing each line to the file, which ends up in only the last line being written.

Comment: You should provide input and expected output examples if you want any more help about the replacement logic.

Comment: I used below and its working fine                                                                       $replacedContent = $_ -replace $([regex]::Escape($string_to_be_replaced)),$member
 [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($datafile2, $replacedContent + "`r`n", $encoding)

Answer (score 0):

[System.IO.File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx) is getting either an array of strings or an IEnumerable of strings as second parameter and cannot be piped to a command because it is not a CmdLet handling pipeline input but a .NET Framework method.

You should try storing your replaced content into a `string[]`to use it as parameter when saving the file.

```
param(
    [String]$file
)

$encoding =[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1')
$replacedContent = [string[]]@(Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object {
    # Do stuff
})
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, $replacedContent, $encoding)
```

Comment: Many thanks for sharing this code. I tried it as you suggested, but getting below error                                                                                                       "param : The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: I made param as the first line, but now sure where should I set the varable $File ? Also I have declared few other variables, so where should I decalre them or assign values/filenames to them?

Comment: I executed the script by passing the value for parameter $file while invoking the script ./scriptname.ps1 ABCD.SCHEMA.TABLE.DAT. However the replacement did not happen in file ABCD.SCHEMA.TABLE.DAT.

Comment: I see that script is not processing or skipping the stuff assigned to $replacedContent. I called my script as ./scriptname -file "filname" . I executed this script from the file path location, so did not give absolute path